# How to Sum a single Column based on grouping in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having a Two Tables one is Sales and another one is BrandMaster

> My Requirement : How to Sum a single Column based on grouping in MySQL

The Structure and Data of Sales Table:

```
SNo            BID          Amount
-----------------------------------
101             1            200
102             2            500
103             5            800
104             8            250
105             1            200
106             2            500
107             5            800
108             8            250
```

The Structure and Data of BrandMaster Table:

```
BID           BrandName          
-------------------------
1             Prod#1
2             Prod#2
3             Prod#3
4             Prod#4
5             Prod#5
6             Prod#6
7             Prod#7
8             Prod#8
```

My Expected Output:

```
BID           SumAmount          
-------------------------
1             400
2             500
3             0
4             0
5             0
6             1600
7             0
8             500
```

The Sales Table contains the BrandID 'BID' and the Sales Amount with Sales ID 'SNo'. I need the Sum of Sales Amount for each Product. Kindly assist me.

Comment: Left join brand master table on sales using the BID field and sum the amount.

Comment: @Shadow I tried it... It gives the entire total not an expected output.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan -- show what you tried.  This is pretty basic aggregation.  If you are getting the entire sum, chances are you need to include a `group by` clause...

Comment: Come on. Try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this 
[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10af3b/6)

```
SELECT
    BrandMaster.BID,          
    IFNULL(SUM(Sales.Amount),0) AS SumAmount
FROM BrandMaster 
    LEFT JOIN Sales ON ( BrandMaster.BID=Sales.BID )
GROUP BY
    BrandMaster.BID
ORDER BY 
    BrandMaster.BID,
    Sales.SNo
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

```
SELECT db.sales.bid AS "BID",
    <AGGREGATE>(db.sales.amount) AS "SumAmount"
    FROM db.sales
    GROUP BY db.sales.bid
    ORDER BY db.sales.bid;
```

Edit: `db` is your database, and `sales` is your, "Sales," table.

Second Edit: replace `<AGGREGATE>` with something from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: Missing something, like an `aggregate`?

Comment: @sgeddes i prefer it the way it is - gives the OP something to do .

Comment: @Strawberry -- fair enough :)