# How to Sum a single Column based on multi grouping in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having a Two Tables one is Sales and another one is BrandMaster

My Requirement : How to Sum a single Column based on **multi grouping** in MySQL

The Structure and Data of Sales Table:

```
SNo            BID          Amount
-----------------------------------
101             1            200
102             2            500
103             5            800
104             8            250
105             1            200
106             2            500
107             5            800
108             8            250
```

The Structure and Data of BrandMaster Table:

```
BID           BrandName          
-------------------------
1             Prod#1
2             Prod#2
3             Prod#3
4             Prod#4
5             Prod#5
6             Prod#6
7             Prod#7
8             Prod#8
```

My Expected Output:

```
BrandName           SumAmount          
-------------------------
Prod#1                  400
Prod#2 and Prod#3       500
Prod#4                    0
Prod#5                    0
Prod#6 and Prod#8      2100
Prod#7                    0
```

The Sales Table contains the BrandID 'BID' and the Sales Amount with Sales ID 'SNo'. I need the Sum of Sales Amount for each Product and Multi Product. Kindly assist me.

Reference Post: [How to Sum a single Column based on grouping in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729678/how-to-sum-a-single-column-based-on-grouping-in-mysql)

Comment: so why are `prod#2` and `prod#3` together? Is the grouping information on someplace else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something with a `CASE`

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales S
JOIN BrandMaster B
  ON S.`BID` = B.`BID`
GROUP BY CASE WHEN `BrandName` = 'Prod-1' THEN 'Prod-1'
              WHEN `BrandName` = 'Prod-2' 
                OR `BrandName` = 'Prod-3' THEN 'Prod-2 & Prod-3'
              WHEN `BrandName` = 'Prod-4' THEN 'Prod-4'
              WHEN `BrandName` = 'Prod-5' THEN 'Prod-5'
              WHEN `BrandName` = 'Prod-6'               
                OR `BrandName` = 'Prod-8' THEN 'Prod-6 & Prod-8'
              WHEN `BrandName` = 'Prod-7' THEN 'Prod-7'
          END
```